# Array Combine in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

I am trying to combine keys and values in arrays. I have an product_id with different price. 
Let say

```
Product id and price 

id 101 and price is 100

id 105 and price is 200

id 101 and price is 300
```

list of product ids in array with `$product_ids[]` and list of price also `$price_amount[]` 
So I preferred to combine the two arrays using `array_combine`

I made `array_combine($product_ids,$price_amount);`
Now it appears look like this way

```
array(2) { [101]=> float(100) [105]=> float(300) }
```

Is there is a way to add the key elements to the id as something like

```
array(2) {
    [101] => float(400) (100+300)
    [105] => float(300)
}
```

Here is the idea i tried

```
 $products = array();
 $order_totalss = array();

      foreach (get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish') as $order) {
                $order = new WC_Order($order->ID);
               if (wc_customer_bought_product($order->billing_email, $order->user_id, $product_id)) {
                    $productcounts[] = $product_id;
                    $order_totalss[] = $order->get_total();
                }

    }
    $arraymergeme = array_combine($productcounts, $order_totalss);
```

Comment: How can you have `101` repeating in `$product_ids`?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger `$product_ids = array(101, 101);`

Comment: @Fresher please show examples of your source arrays with real working code, it is confusing with a text description.

Comment: how come an id 101 have two price tags 100 & 300? even so, if its a database record, IMO you should sum your price and `group by id`

Comment: @Bsienn It is variable price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code so you can see what's happening clearly:

```
$ids    = array(101, 105, 101);
$prices = array(100, 200, 300);

$totals = array();
foreach ($ids as $key => $id)
{
    // Make sure index is defined
    if ( ! isset($totals[$id]))
    {
        // Make sure we have a value
        $totals[$id] = 0;
    }

    // Assuming index $key matches... add to the total
    $totals[$id] += $prices[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this manually I'm afraid:

```
$total = array();
foreach ($product_ids as $key => $value) {
    // each value of product_ids becomes the key
    if (isset($total[$value])) {
        // we have seen this key before
        $total[$value] += $price_amount[$key];
    } else {
        // new key
        $total[$value] = $price_amount[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays are associative so you can write something like: `price['101'] = 100` thereby using the product id as the array index.

Comment: Problem is he's got duplicate product ids, so the index would be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking you are looking for something like this. I haven't done php in awhile, so the syntax may need tweaking, but I think the logic is correct.

```
$cart = array(
    "101" => 100, 
    "105" => 200, 
    "101" => 300
);

$product_id_arr = array();

foreach ($cart as $product_id => $price) {
    if(array_key_exists($product_id, $product_id_arr)){
        $product_id_arr[$product_id] = $product_id_arr[$product_id] + $price;
    }else{
        $product_id_arr[$product_id] = $price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. i have a product ids as in array like array(101,105,101) and price as array(100,300,200) in this case i want to combine the array but it omitting the duplicate id by default (default behavior) so in this case i want to add the values if the same id is present i mean 100+300 to the id 101

Answer (score 1):

`array_combine` will not do the trick for you. You will have to iterate through the array and total them as you go. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$product_ids = array('101', '105', '101');
$price_amount = array(100, 200, 300);
$combined = array();

$productCount = count($product_ids);
for($i = 0; $i < $productCount; $i++) {

    // if this product_id is not in the $combined array, add its price
    // as associative array ('101'=>100)
    // but if it is found in $combined, add to its current price
    if (!array_key_exists($product_ids[$i], $combined)) {
        $combined[$product_ids[$i]] = $price_amount[$i];
    } else {
        $combined[$product_ids[$i]] += $price_amount[$i]; 
    }
}

print_r($combined);
?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [101] => 400
    [105] => 200
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$final_arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($product_ids);$i++) {
    if(!isset($final_arr[$product_ids[$i]])) {
        $final_arr[$product_ids[$i]] = 0;
    }
    $final_arr[$product_ids[$i]] += $price_amount[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add key elements to id, basically an array can be created by using the `array()` language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated `key => value` pairs as arguments.

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

the one you are looking for is associative array. you can definitely specify the key you want and store the value you want at that key.

here is a [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that would be helpful